# jQuery: Why can't I get this animation to repeat?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, repeat

html:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="" class="two">
    <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="" class="one">    
    <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="" class="tri">
    <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="" class="four">
    <img src="images/05.jpg" alt="" class="five">
</div>
```

css:

```
.one, .two, .tri, .four, .five {position: absolute;}  
.two {bottom: 0;}
.tri {left: -348px;}
.four {left: 348px; top: 19.8em;}
.five {right: -257px;}
```

This is the animation:

```
var one = $('.one');
var two = $('.two');
var tri = $('.tri');
var four = $('.four');
var five = $('.five');

$(two, tri, four, five).hide();

//first image
$(one).animate({
        'top' : '-17.5em'
    }, 8000, function() {
        $(two).show();
        $(one).delay(6000).fadeOut(1500);
    });

    //second image
    $(two).delay(13700).animate({
        'bottom' : '-30.7em'
    }, 11000, function() {
        $(tri, four, five).show();
        $(two).delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
    });

    //third/fourth/fifth image
    $(tri).delay(31500).animate({
        'left' : '0'
    }, 600, function() {
        $(tri).delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $(four).delay(31500).animate({
        'top' : '0'
    }, 600, function() {
        $(four).delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $(five).delay(31500).animate({
        'right' : '0'
    }, 600, function() {
        $(one).delay(5000).css({'top' : '0'}).fadeIn();
        $(five).delay(6000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
```

(I've tried putting it into callback functions, but couldn't make it work, so I used delays. I know it's sort of a different question, but if anyone has any idea why callbacks didn't work, please tell)

Anyway, I'm trying to get this animation to repeat indefinitely. I've tried setInterval, I've tried putting it into a function, then calling it again from within itself, and generally any potential solution I could find online, but nothing seems to work. 
Any help you can give me would be much appreciated.

Comment: To repeat something indefinitely, a `setInterval` should work just fine. Something else must be going on.

Comment: I know it's a hassle, but can you please post an example of using setInterval with the above code? I've tried, but it either doesn't work at all, or it runs once but doesn't repeat.

Comment: You could wrap your animation in a callback fct und call this fct in a while loop. Maybe this helps: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/looping-jquery-function-animation-solved

Answer (score 0):

try this up

```
var ctr = 0;
function animate_me(){
++ctr;
//your code;
console.log('animating... #'+ ctr);

//setTimeout(animate_me, 6000);
setTimeout(animate_me, 1500);
}

$(function() {
    animate_me();
});
```

Comment: thanks so much, fedmich. I've tried it, and it does the same thing: it runs once, and then nothing. I don't get it.

Comment: try it and look at the console. it will keep on adding 1,2,3 after 1.5 seconds